# PHP 5.6 not used by Apache instead it uses PHP 5.5

Tags: server, apache2, php

I am trying to upgrade my PHP version from 5.5 to 5.6 so I can get Laravel working. So I followed the instructions from [here](https://www.dev-metal.com/install-setup-php-5-6-ubuntu-14-04-lts/) but instead of adding this repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6
```

I added this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
```

anything else didn't work. Afterwards I installed PHP and to test the version I did this:

```
php -v
```

which gave me this:

```
PHP 5.6.28-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
```

however when I navigate to the server in my browser phpinfo() showed this:

```
PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20
```

Why is that happening, why isn't Apache loading the new version?

Also, in my /etc folder I have two php folders one is: /etc/php5 (which I think contains php5.5) and another called: /etc/php (which I think contains php5.6).

Answer (score 4):

I found out that I have the following files inside /etc/apache2/mods-available/

```
php5.6.conf
php5.6.load
php5.conf
php5.load
php5filter.conf
php5filter.load
php7.0.conf
php7.0.load
```

so what I did is the following

```
sudo a2dismod php5.load
```

and then

```
sudo a2enmod php5.6.load
```

that switched the version the apache was using to 5.6 and voila problem solved : )